# Which techniques to follow to make a fast and consistent message consumer that writes to a RDBMS

Tags: message-queue, producer-consumer, consistency

I am building a consumer application that reads messages from a queue and runs basic sanitization and deduplication and persists them to an RDBMS.

The functional requirements are

- messages must not be lost
- Validate and sanitize the arriving messages before persisting them.
- Invalid messages go to the database in an error table with an error code.
- Valid messages go to the database in the main table.

Non functional requirements

- The database must have every single record that arrived from the queue (valid or invalid).
- The system must process 1-5 million records per hour or more.

Tech stack used

- spring boot cloud stream (consumer stack)
- Solace pubsub+ for message queue
- Sql server as the database

Points to note:

- My deduplication checks the database against every query - something I don't like.
- The application uses two uuids in the message payload as the primary key so no query is wasted to fetch next primary keys in the database. The combination of these two uuids will almost never collide.
- I use 10 concurrent consumers to speed up the message consumptions.

What optimizations can I make to the above system to make the writes fast and still consistent?

Comment: sounds like 99% of the work is done by the db. you might have rethink what "duplicate" really means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, my first design choice likely would have been Kafka.
It scales, it has a terrific story for exactly-once delivery
with causal ordering, and the log replay comes in very handy,
both in dev and during exceptional events in prod.

> messages must not be lost

Good. Looks like you'll have to use Solace at-least-once delivery.
And then de-dup becomes interesting.

> 5 million records per hour

So 1400 row/second, more during peak bursts.
Backend is a SQL server; I recommend you adopt
Postgres with partitioned table.
Bench it to verify throughput in your environment.
Then bench end-to-end, with Solace plus backend.

It's unclear why you chose ten workers.
Typically we measure first, then size appropriately.
Let's assume each worker must handle 140 row/second.
Sounds reasonable.

The most important thing to work out at this stage
of the design is your dedup approach. It sounds like
the source data can produce duplicates. And Solace
can produce dups, for example around the time that
servers reboot. At the time it is originally created,
there is *something* about a record that makes it
"unique" at app level, some subset of its fields.
And we can hash those fields. Ideally you would
route on the hash. Failing that you can identify
ten or more values of field `f1`, or values of
some `(f1, f2, f3)` tuple, that can be assigned
across the ten workers for somewhat even loading.
It sounds like your `uuid1` field fits the bill.
I'm not sure what's going on with your `uuid2` field,
perhaps you feel 128 random bits doesn't offer
collision safety and you need the catenated 256.

DB tables will have compound Primary Key of `(uuid1, uuid2)`.
Or perhaps you decide that `uuid1` suffices,
and `uuid2` is simply stored as an attribute.
We store [UUIDs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-uuid.html)
on-disk in efficient binary form.

We have many messages flowing through the system,
and there *will* be `m1, m2` duplicate pairs.
The key is to ensure that if `m1` & `m2` could
potentially be dups, they *will* be routed to
the same worker. That lets workers maintain
an in-memory [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Usual_implementation)
of recently seen messages. Write down a specification
for max delay a dup message might experience. That will
let you size the pqueue appropriately. When workers
come and go, there can still be room to lose, so
the backend's unique PK index is still the final dup arbiter.
Be prepared to see an INSERT / COMMIT occasionally fail
with "unique constraint violated", and go back to carefully
insert rows one-by-one, or at least send them to a table
on the side where another worker can spend time carefully
inserting them.

Which brings us to batch size.

There is no way you can possibly COMMIT single rows at a time,
you just won't be able to keep up with offered load.
As a rule of thumb, it is usually desirable for bulk inserts
to send around 500 msec of work to the DB, and no more
than 5 seconds worth. More than that isn't *bad*,
it just won't see any throughput gains, there's no
more network and I/O latency for us to amortize over.

So your minimum batch size is likely to be ~ 70 rows being inserted
per COMMIT. Benchmark this early in the project, and verify your
ten workers all get along with one another. This will inform
your table partitioning strategy. Likely you will want backend
sharding to match how you're routing messages to workers,
based on same field(s).

Let's talk about timestamps.

Inevitably you will want to do reporting on recent rows,
and at some point you will discard ancient rows.
Hopefully the origin generates timestamps, using NTP
synchronized clocks. Write down the max permitted skew.
Part of your validation process will be to sanity check stamps
and declare error for bad timestamp.

Consider putting some form of timestamp, maybe with daily
or hourly granularity, at the front of your compound PK,
to keep recent rows together. It will make a huge performance
difference for anything that reports on recently arrived rows.
It will also make it easier to quickly prune ancient rows.
If your partitioning scheme exposes such timestamps, then
a DROP is the ideal way to discard year-old rows.

It has been said that the man who has two wristwatches
never knows what time it is. There may be some temptation
to tack on a timestamp as messages encounter one layer
or another. Resist that temptation. If you *do* succumb,
and add a `received_at` column, be sure to write down
the semantics. That way maintainers a year or two down
the road will know whether they should be examining a
date range based on *this* stamp or *that* one.

Comment: Thank you for the response! A lot of information there. I can already identify some nice tricks that I can already use. Do add to it if you have any other ideas.